# C++ overloading the '=' operator cause crash

Tags: c++

I have a problem on my simple function to overload the operator '='.
Here's the code:
class definition:

```
class SeqMat{
private:
      elem* punt;
      SeqMat(const SeqMat&);
public:
      SeqMat();
      void insMat(int, int);
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const SeqMat&);
      SeqMat& operator-=(int);
      ~SeqMat();
      SeqMat& operator~();
      SeqMat& operator=(const SeqMat&);
};
```

Function:

```
SeqMat& SeqMat::operator=(const SeqMat& lista){
    if (this != &lista){
        delete punt;
        punt = lista.punt;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

When I run the compiled .exe, the program stops working like in this screen:
[image]

Here's the right code:

```
SeqMat& SeqMat::operator=(const SeqMat& lista) {
elem* punt1;
elem* punt2;
punt2 = lista.punt;
punt1 = new elem;
delete punt;
punt = punt1;
while (punt2 != nullptr){
    punt1->numero = punt2->numero;
    punt1->ripetizioni = punt2->ripetizioni;
    punt2 = punt2->pun;
    if (punt2 == nullptr){
        punt1->pun = nullptr;
        break;
    }
    else{
        punt1->pun = new elem;
        punt1 = punt1->pun;
    }
}
punt1 = nullptr;
return *this;
```

}

Comment: You have two objects pointing to the same `elem`. They're going to both try to `delete` it, as they think they both own it. You probably want to create a "deep" copy rather than a "shallow" copy (or, if you do want a shallow copy, implement proper sharing semantics, i.e. with `std::shared_ptr`)

Comment: You don't copy the punt (presumably) array of the other object, you just share it between two objects. If you used vectors, you wouldn't need any operator= or copy constructor any more. It would just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function

```
SeqMat& SeqMat::operator=(const SeqMat& lista)
```

is a "copy" operation.  It is making `*this` be a *copy* of `lista`.

As such, you shouldn't be `delete`-ing more than you are `new`-ing.  Copying shouldn't make *fewer things exist*.

As such - based on the code you're showing - it should look something like:

```
SeqMat& SeqMat::operator=(const SeqMat& lista){
    if (this != &lista){
        delete punt;
        punt = new elem(lista.punt); // Make a COPY
    }
    return *this;
}
```

At the very least, you should be thinking about whether `elem* punt` should be **unique for each object** or **shared**.

If it's unique for each object, you shouldn't share pointers to the same data.  And if it's shared, you shouldn't be so eager to have one object `delete` the pointer.

Comment: If `Mat` stands for "matrix" with more than one `elem`, then either an array-new or a recursive deep copy will be needed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter +1 ... very good point.  As it's stated, the question requires more than a bit of guesswork, so hopefully this will be a *push in the right direction*.

Comment: I solved the problem with the copy member to member of the list, I am truly grateful you.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not show your main executed code, I do not know if the crash has directly relation with the operator= overloading. But it still has some problem with your code:

1. Generally, you should use smart pointer if you wrap some resource in you class. Here, if punt is created by planned or in other place, we can see it as resource.
2. You should definitely know what do you want in the operator= overloading(shallow copy or deep copy).

(1) if punt is a type of resource, shallow copy required, and shallow copy is always delegated by smart pointer here(shared_ptr, unique_ptr or other).

(2) if punt is not a type of resource, and you want to use deep copy, a typical deep copy code should like this:

```
SeqMat& SeqMat::operator=(const SeqMat& lista) {
    if (this != &lista){
        SeqMat *pOrgin = punt;        //remember the origin pointer, to confirm that the punt get the correct value then deleted
        punt = new elem(lista.punt); // Make a COPY
        delete pOrigin;
    }
    return *this;
}
```